# Python and numpy - removing rows from a corresponding matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy.

I have one array `Y` and one matrix `X`.  This is for a regression.  They arrays has labels, e.g. `0,1,2,3,4,5`.  I need to create a new array that has label `0` removed for all rows and the corresponding row in `X` removed as well.  What is the most efficient means to do this?

e.g.

```
for i in xrange(y.shape):
    if y==0:
       pop y pop X
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy arrays are not good at appending/removing rows. If you know which rows are to be deleted, just extract the other rows (you need) and create a new array.

I don't understand your question very well, so please correct me if I am wrong:

```
x = x[y != 0]
y = y[y != 0]
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23], [31, 32, 33]])
y = np.array([1, 0, 3])
x = x[y != 0]
y = y[y != 0]
```

now:

```
x == array([[11, 12, 13],
            [31, 32, 33]])
y == array([1, 3])
```

Comment: I just want to remove all labels in the array y == 0 and remove the corresponding row in X

Comment: Tampa - then it is exactly what you need - remove all elements `== 0` from `y` and the corresponding from `x`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you will always have that empty row no matter what, I don't see why you even need NUMPY to do this...

```
Z = Z[:][1:]
```

If it's just the first row this will actually work for the matrix, and of course the array

```
Z = Z[1:]
```

I like @eumiro's solution if you don't care about the placement of the items in the matrix, but their solution will remove all zeros and shift elements I believe.